# How to check for a css class name in a specific html element with capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I want to test that my specific `tr` element gets a `selected` css class added to it when I click a cell. I want to identify the specific row by its text, then click a cell in the row, and then check its css classes.

This code that checks for this css within the entire page seems to work:

```
row = find(:xpath, "//tr[contains(., 'My Text')]")
cell = find(:xpath, "//tr[contains(., 'My Text')]/td")
expect(page).to_not have_css("tr.selected") # success
cell.click
expect(page).to have_css("tr.selected") # success
```

...but I'd like to limit my search to the specific row object. This code does not ever find css that I'm looking for and always fails the last `expect`.

```
row = find(:xpath, "//tr[contains(., 'My Text')]")
cell = find(:xpath, "//tr[contains(., 'My Text')]/td")
expect(row).to_not have_css("tr.selected")
cell.click
expect(row).to have_css("tr.selected") # fails
```

When I look at `row[:class]` after the `click` I see 'selected' in its list of classes.  How can I correctly limit my test to look for the `.selected` class only within my specific row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`have_css` checks for descendants, to check the current element you want `match_css`

```
row = find(:xpath, "//tr[contains(., 'My Text')]")
cell = row.find('td')
expect(row).to_not match_css("tr.selected")
cell.click
expect(row).to match_css("tr.selected")
```

Also, if you don't have a specific need to use XPath

```
row = find('tr:not(.selected)', text: 'My Text')
row.find('td').click
expect(row).to match_css('tr.selected')
```

reads much better

Comment: Ah, perfect.  Thanks for the tips!